# inserting dialogbox within condition in android

Tags: android, sql-server, if-statement, dialog

i created an apps which insert data to sql server.there is no problem in connecting to the server . but i want to use a dialog box when user enters same data which already been inserted to database .but i don't know why it is not working...

my code is here.....

```
public void insert(){
            final String fname=name.getText().toString();
            final String fcity=city.getText().toString();
             ResultSet rs;
             try{
             Statement statement1=connect.createStatement();
             rs=statement1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM FORM1");
             List<Map<String,String>>data1=null;
             data1=new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

             while(rs.next()){
                 Map<String,String>datanum1=new HashMap<String,String>();
                 datanum1.put("a", rs.getString("NAME"));
                 datanum1.put("b", rs.getString("CITY"));
                 data1.add(datanum1);
             }
             if(data1.contains(fname)!=false){
                 AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                 adb.setTitle("My Records");
                 adb.setMessage(fname+" Already exist... do u want to overwrite???");
                 adb.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try{
                         Statement statement2=connect.createStatement();
                        statement2.executeUpdate("UPDATE FORM1 SET NAME='"+fname+"',CITY='"+fcity+"' WHERE NAME='fname'");
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
                        }

                    }
                });
                 adb.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                 AlertDialog adbc=adb.create();
                 adbc.show();
             }
             else{
                 Statement statement3=connect.createStatement();
                 statement3.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO FORM1(NAME,CITY) VALUES('"+name.getText().toString()+"','"+city.getText().toString()+"')");
             }

             }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage()); 
             }
         }
```

if any one please  tell me what mistake i have done and what is correct code to use....

Comment: Are you doing this insert from the UI thread?

Comment: yes.....through a button

Comment: and what do you mean by it is not working? What exactly is the problem you are facing?
Also. modify `if(data1.contains(fname)!=false)` to `if(data1.contains(fname))` ...readability will be better

Comment: if i enetr same data again ..it is not showing any dialog box..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are showing up the dialog in UI thread only. If it is not calling from ui Thread, just use runOnUiThread(..) method as follows:

### -----

```
if(data1.contains(fname)!=false){

 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                 AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                 adb.setTitle("My Records");
                 adb.setMessage(fname+" Already exist... do u want to overwrite???");
                 adb.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        try{
                         Statement statement2=connect.createStatement();
                        statement2.executeUpdate("UPDATE FORM1 SET NAME='"+fname+"',CITY='"+fcity+"' WHERE NAME='fname'");
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
                        }

                    }
                });
                 adb.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                 AlertDialog adbc=adb.create();
                 adbc.show();
    }
        });
         }
```

Comment: explain what you are expecting and what is actually happening while running your code

Comment: i just want that when i enter name in my edit text and click save button , a dialogbox should be opened if name is already been exist in database.but it is not displaying....that is the problem

Comment: I would suggest you to debug your code to see if control comes inside the if condition if(data1.contains(fname)!=false){.. Put a break point there , and see if it is coming or not.. then do single step execution and try to figure out where is the issue

Comment: if i using if(data1.contains(fname)) still same result appeared